# Convert 32bpp bitmap to 256 colors

Tags: c++, bitmap

I want to convert 32bpp bitmap to 256 colors, without using color palette. Is there a way to do this?

My main objective to reduce the colors is to decrease the image size as this image has to transferred over socket across internet.

**Note:** I don't want to use color palette for 256 color bitmaps.

Thanks in advance.
Paul

Comment: Which bitmap format are you using? That has 8 bit RGB pixels?

Comment: am using 32 bit bitmap which has 4 bytes for each pixel...this 32bit bitmap, i want to convert to 8bit and reduce the colors to 256, without using color palette.

Comment: You want to compress that into 1 byte? Then uncompress at the server? If difference between two pixel is relatively small, you can do a simple additinal compression or you can get the most probable pixel value and take that as a base then send the server the differences from the most probable pixel(@ 1 byte resolution)

Comment: The source format is largely irrelevant. What format do you intend to convert to that has 8 bit RGB pixels?

Comment: hi huseyin, your answer is not clear. my basic requirement is to reduce the bitmap color to 256 so that the bitmap's size will be reduced, which in turn decreases the latency for transferring over socket.

Comment: You're pretty much stuck with the fact that 256-color formats almost universally use a palette. There's a good reason for this too: with a direct mapping (i.e., something that doesn't use a palette) from 8 to 32 bits, it's going to be nearly impossible to achieve decent quality. Perhaps you could use something on the order of JPEG compression instead?

Comment: hi jerry, am not very much concerned about the quality, all i want is reduction in bitmap size. if quality is low even then its fine :). i cant use jpeg compression.

Comment: hi david, yes i want to convert to 8bit RGB pixels but with out palette. and source has 32bit RGB pixels.

Comment: Are you intending to un-compress the bitmap after transmission so you get back 32-bit RGB pixels that display without a palette?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a palette when it is likely the best way to solve the problem?  This seems like a bit of an XY problem with flawed requirements.

Comment: hi tim, yes i will un-compress them, but they should be 8-bit RGB pixels. i want to convert 32-bit RGB pixels to 8-bit RGB pixels without color palette. Quality is not a concern.

Comment: hi Retired Ninja, the basic idea is to encode the 8 bit image to H264 video streams and send them over socket. using palette for h264 compression gives me a distorted image at the client end after decompressing.

Comment: So, you want to encode a 32bpp image to 8bpp then encode that as a video frame and send it somewhere?  It's likely you'd get better results/compression just encoding straight to video with lossy compression.

Comment: @user If "quality is not a concern", why do you care about distorted images?

Comment: yes this is my idea for making send faster. But directly encoding 32 bpp image to video with lossy compression leads to lagging at the client end, which means the video frame size is still high, this i want to reduce by decreasing the colors of the source image before encoding them to video. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong, as am not an expert in this field.

Comment: hi David, when i meant quality this is at the image color levels, not at the basic image itself. If there are some mismatches with colors that fine, but image should be proper. for example at the place "X" in the explorer window i cant have some lines, but having different color for "X" is fine.

Comment: Putting the image into such narrow colour channels will lead to appallingly poor images. Have you experimented at all in an image program?

Comment: yes...i have been trying this from last 2 weeks, after running out of all the ideas, am came here anticipating some expert help.

Comment: I believe you're going about this the wrong way.  Assuming the lag on your client is due to the amount of data you're sending and not the time it takes to decode the data then you should look into configuring the codec you're using to lower the bitrate.  If that's not possible then resizing the images to create smaller frames is probably your best bet.

Comment: @user3239282 In what way have you not received expert help?

Comment: hi retired ninja, you are absolutely correct decoding is not taking longer time but the size of the data is the bottleneck, dont you think reducing the color will decrease the size of the data. And wat do u mean by resizing the images to create smaller frames can you please elaborate your suggestion.

Comment: hi david, am anticipating expert help. it doesn't mean i have not received expert help.

Comment: AFAIK, most practical image/video compression algorithms use "true color" or 8-bit grayscale images as the source. To further encode 8-bit image with H.264 or MJPEG for example would require an additional 8-bit to 24/32-bit converter in between -- increasing the latency and decreasing the quality.

Comment: As @AkiSuihkonen said, reducing the colors is unlikely to help as video codecs use their own color format when encoding.  Resizing the frames is just that, instead of sending a 640x480 video try a 320x240 video and scale it up on the client.  If you had asked how to reduce the bandwidth requirement for a video stream in the first place and explained what library you're using to encode it you'd probably get more useful answers.

Comment: hi Retired Ninja, i will try this. Am using libx264 library for encoding and ffmpeg for decoding. Can you please let me know, how i can do this, do i need to use sws_scale for resizing the video. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you use 3 bits for red and green, and 2 bits for blue, and ignore alpha. Then you have 8 red colours, 8 green colours and 4 blue colours. You need to map 256 colours red, green and blue channels down to those 8 or 4 colours. The naive approach:

- For red and green, the 3 bit channels, divide source channel value by 32.
- For blue, the 4 bit channel, divide by 64.

Obviously you can divide up the available 8 bits any way you like. You can choose different ways to go from 8 bit channels to 2 or 3 bit channels. And so on.

I don't know a commonly used 8 bit pixel bitmap format that does not use a palette. So I think you'll have to roll this yourself. Don't expect very good results in terms of visual similarity between the original and the reduced colour depth images.

Comment: hi david, thanks for the algo. but i want to convert 32 bit bitmap to 256 colors.

Comment: There's nothing to share. Divide by 32 is, well, `x/32` for instance. I can't be more specific because you asked a general question. No mention of specific bitmap formats.

Comment: +1: possibly the best way of answering this flawed queestion.

Comment: hi Bathsehba, can you please let me, how this question is flawed?

Answer (score 0):

I think, may be, you just convert you 32bits bitmap to 8bits bitmap, that is 256 colors exactly.

Comment: That simply states the goal as expressed in the question

Comment: I'm sorry. There's not a standard image format with 8-bit that support colours. En, there's a format not applicable with 8-bit. it's R3G3B2, that is, 8-bit image format using 3 bits for red, 3bits for green, and 2 bits for blue.